# How to replace OpenSSL with LibreSSL globally?

Tags: nixos, nix

In light of the upcoming *critical* [OpenSSL 3.0.7 security fix](https://mta.openssl.org/pipermail/openssl-announce/2022-October/000238.html), how do I change NixOS over to use LibreSSL globally instead of OpenSSL?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [official GitHub page](https://github.com/libressl-portable/portable/tree/0c8231e298f6d0384591a5e1b88564be7d37772e#compatibility-with-openssl):

> Compatibility with OpenSSL:

> LibreSSL is API compatible with OpenSSL 1.0.1, but does not yet include all new APIs from OpenSSL 1.0.2 and later. LibreSSL also includes APIs not yet present in OpenSSL. The current common API subset is OpenSSL 1.0.1.

> LibreSSL is not ABI compatible with any release of OpenSSL, or necessarily earlier releases of LibreSSL. You will need to relink your programs to LibreSSL in order to use it, just as in moving between major versions of OpenSSL. LibreSSL's installed library version numbers are incremented to account for ABI and API changes.

TLDR: You can't. That will require extensive patching of source code and recompilation.